# Duda sobre formato de video

Tags: html5, css3, video

En mi sitio tengo un video, el cuál subí en 3 formatos diferentes. Esto hace que a veces tarde bastante en cargar mi sitio.
¿Está bien si dejo un solo formato y los otros dos los saco? ¿Cuál formato me conviene dejar que sea compatible con todos o la mayoría de los navegadores tanto para escritorio como para teléfono?

Estos son los formatos en los que lo subí:

```html
<video muted loop id=myVideo data-autoplay poster=imgs/video.jpg>
<source src=imgs/videos/entrada.mp4 type=video/mp4>
<source src=imgs/videos/entrada.ogg type=video/ogg>
<source src=imgs/videos/entrada.webm type=video/webm>
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿Está bien si dejo un solo formato y los otros dos los saco?

Cuando [`video`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) se utiliza con [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) lo que sucede es:

> No todos los navegadores admiten los mismos [formatos de video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats); se puede proporcionar múltiples fuentes dentro de elementos `<source>` anidados, **y el navegador usará el primero que entienda**

Por lo que esto es lo mejor que puede hacer para evitar problemas de formatos no compatibles.

El navegador seleccionará uno (*el soportado*) y procederá a descargar únicamente el elegido.

---

> ¿Cuál formato me conviene dejar que sea compatible con todos o la mayoría de los navegadores tanto para escritorio como para teléfono?

[Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility) puede ver el soporte de los distintos navegadores respecto a los distintos formatos de video.

Los soportado por las mayoría de los navegadores son:

- `MP4 H.264 (codec video) MP3 (codec audio)`
- `MP4 H.264 (codec video) AAC (codec audio)`

---

Teniendo en cuenta lo anteriormente señalado y si decides continuar dando múltiples opciones deberías considerar cambiar el orden de los `<source>`

#### Ejemplo:

```
<video muted loop id=myVideo data-autoplay poster=imgs/video.jpg>
  <source src=imgs/videos/entrada.webm type=video/webm>
  <source src=imgs/videos/entrada.ogg type=video/ogg>
  <source src=imgs/videos/entrada.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

Comment: Al cambiar de lugar los `source`qué estaría consiguiendo? Creo que no entendí para qué sirve

Comment: Por ejemplo `webm` es un formato nuevo el cual posee una buena calidad visual a bajo peso (_alta compresión => web friendly_). Este formato esta comenzando a ser soportado de poco por todos los principales navegadores por dichas cualidades.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces me conviene ponerlo primero porque ahora es el que los navegadores están entendiendo primero, no?

Comment: Entiendo, y el OGG me conviene dejarlo o mejor lo quito? Lo que estoy buscando principalmente es acelerar la carga de mi sitio, por eso pensaba en quitar un formato y eliminar ese video del servidor

Comment: @CarlaPaludetto, dejarlo o quitarlo es una opinión/decisión personal. Si el objetivo real es acelerar la carga, entonces deberías implementar [`lazy load`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033115/delay-loading-of-html5-video) del video, imagenes, etc.

Comment: Eso lo estoy implementando con el `data-autoplay`. Creo que con eso debería funcionar ya

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos. Voy a hacer lo que me sugeriste entonces!